# IPad: can I deal with landscape, portrait orientations solely in interface builder? (non-programmatically)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder

Let's say we have a very simple view with just a single button.

I'd like this button to flip when the user rotates his ipad. What's the simplest way to do this? Maybe interface builder has some kind of property I can set? I keep hearing something about autoresizingmask but I can't really find it in interface builder.

Thanks

p.s I understand that for more complex views I might need to create two separate views one for landscape and one for portrait and then swap them programmatically with some kind of event. but I'm wondering if for very simple views we can do something easily with interface builder with no need for any code or additional views?

Answer (score 2):

actually i found a pretty simple tutorial that explains this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3yb24f8O1Y
then
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lzbVURh4mM